# How to access google cloud storage object with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-storage

I am new here, 

is there any good simple way to access "google cloud storage" object with "jQuery ajax"?

What I understand so far is it use REST and I had to setup my [Request Headers](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods) and authorize the access with OAuth 2.0 or generate my [signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs), and enable the "CORS on the Bucket" with "gsutil setcors".

I can't piece those information together to get a working sample. Can anyone kindly help to forward a link or a sample to:

1) Get an "object" (say testing.xml) inside a "bucket" (www.testing.com) with "Share Publicly" enabled with jQuery ajax (no authorization require)?

2) Put / delete / get  the object inside a bucket which is not "Share Publicly" (and authorization is needed)?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easier to do with the JSON api, which includes a JavaScript client library. Check it out: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/